# Web APi view model decimal formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I have a ViewModel that needs to return several values from several double datatype properties.  I tried to use DisplayFormat data annotation to make sure the doubles are returned to two decimal places.

This did not work as there are several fields that are returning a lot of decimals.  What can I do to ensure that only two decimal places are returned from my Web API view model?

Answer (score 0):

This should sort it out... however if you want to always display the 2 decimal places, you'll have to call this method `.ToString("#.00")`

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private double randomNumber;

    public double RandomNumber 
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Round(randomNumber, 2);     
        }
        set
        {
            randomNumber = value;
        }
    }
}
```